# Difference between Java 6 & java 7 Swing

Tags: java, swing

Could any one give the difference between Java 6 & java 7 [Swing]. As of now what i have come to know is there is a new component JLayer added in java 7, other than this no info is available. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Thank You.

Comment: Getting multiple selected items from a `JList` is actually broken between java 6 and 7 - be aware of that one, or get single selected items (not multiple).

Comment: Lazy questions don't deserve answers.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Took me 7.45 seconds. http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/guides/swing/enhancements-7.html

> **JLayer Class**
>   The JLayer class is a flexible and powerful decorator for Swing components. It enables you to draw on components and respond
>   to component events without modifying the underlying component
>   directly. For more information, read How to Decorate Components with
>   JLayer in the Java Tutorial.
>
> **Nimbus Look & Feel**
>   The Nimbus Look & Feel (L&F) has moved from com.sun.java.swing to a standard API namespace, javax.swing; see the
>   javax.swing.plaf.nimbus package for more information. Although it is
>   not the default L&F, you can easily use it. Consult the Nimbus Look
>   and Feel section in the Java Tutorial for more information and
>   examples of three simple methods for using Nimbus in your
>   applications.
>
> **Heavyweight and Lightweight Components**
>   Historically, mixing heavyweight (AWT) and lightweight (Swing) components in the same
>   container has been problematic. However, mixing heavyweight and
>   lightweight components is easy to accomplish in Java SE 7. The Mixing
>   Heavyweight and Lightweight Components article shows you how.
>
> **Shaped and Translucent Windows**
>   The Java SE 7 release supports windows with transparency and non-rectangular shapes. See How to
>   Create Translucent and Shaped Windows, part of the Java Tutorial.
>
> **Hue-Saturation-Luminance (HSL) Color Selection in JColorChooser Class**
>   An HSV tab has been added to the JColorChooser class, which
>   allows users to select colors using the Hue-Saturation-Luminance (HSL)
>   color model.
>
> In addition, the following technologies feature related enhancements:
>
> - AWT Enhancements in JDK 7
> - Drag n Drop Enhancements in JDK 7

Comment: Thank you for your fast reply, actually even i got it after posting this question, other than these there are no enhancements right. thank you.

Comment: @Jeroen Vannevel please to add Thread-safe methods quietly disappeared from JDK_7

Comment: @mKorbel: It's community wiki so feel free to add it yourself (add a source as well)